# Arranfing user inputs in a given link

Tags: html, jsp, servlets, hyperlink

I have to go to the following adress:

```
/getPath/u/<username1>/u/<username2>
```

However I get username1 and username2 from the user as textbox inputs.
How can I make it in jsp?
I thought about using form, but the inputs are not exectly parameters...

Comment: what do you want to achieve? getPath ? is that a servlet ? or ? Try to explain better plz

Comment: OP want to submit a form to exactly given URL with <username1> and <username2> values provided from input fields.

Comment: parameters in the url are getting after the question mark.